# Change row color by Date compare

Tags: axapta, x++

I need some help me to write a statement. Table with Date - DDataWydania + 2 years > Currentdate. But I need that rows get a different colour if 2 years have passed since inserted Date.

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
    {
        dbContacts _dbContacts;;
        _dbContacts = _record;


        if(_record.(fieldnum(dbContacts,DDataWydania))  == systemDateGet())
          //  DDataWydania + 2 years > Currentdate
        {
            _options.backColor(WinAPI::RGB2int(127,255,0));
           // _options.colorOnSelectedRow(WinApi::RGB2int(64,128,128)); 
        }


       super(_record, _options);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)

{

    int specificColor = WinApi::RGB2int(127,255,0);
    dbContacts _dbContacts;

    ;

    _dbContacts = _record.data();

    if(_dbContacts.DDataWydania != dateNull())
    {        
        if((today() - _dbContacts.DDataWydania) > (365 * 2)) //365 * 2 --> two years
        {             
            _options.backColor(specificColor );    
        }
    }
    super(_record, _options);

}
```

Comment: Great it works. So  this (today() - _dbContacts.DDataWydania) return an int of 'passed' days that can be compared ?

Comment: Yes, can be compared. To see that value you could create an int variable and save the result if you want.

Comment: But what if I have no values in there? On default user fills  Date so before it's declared it also changes colour.  I need to convert the Date somehow to string ? Or is there some easy way

Comment: You can use DateNull() function to check de value, I already updated the answer with that.